# Return an element as a string outputs undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

All the code is in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsaf1btz/), the problem is that the function does not return the expected value, but it does print it on console, I'm not sure what am I doing wrong, any ideas?

EDIT: This is all the code, I'm returning `html` but never get its value

```
//Returns all assistants to specific event
function getAssistants(id) {
let uri = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/uqndk";
$.getJSON(uri, function(data) {
let html = "";

$.each(data.events[id].assistants, function(index, value) {
  if (value == 'undefined' || value == null) {
    html = '<li class="collection-item">No hay asistentes registrados.</li>';
  } else {
    html += '<li class="collection-item">' + value.name + '</li>';
  }
});

//console.log(html);

return html;
});
}

$("#assistants").append(getAssistants(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue happen since you are try to get a return result asynchronous, but in real its asynchronous

see the edit in your code here:

```js
//Returns all assistants to specific event
function getAssistants(id) {
  let uri = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/uqndk";
  $.getJSON(uri, function(data) {
    let html = "";

    $.each(data.events[id].assistants, function(index, value) {
      if (value == 'undefined' || value == null) {
        html = '<li class="collection-item">No hay asistentes registrados.</li>';
      } else {
        html += '<li class="collection-item">' + value.name + '</li>';
      }
    });
    
    //console.log(html);

    $("#assistants").append(html);
  });
}

getAssistants(1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="assistants" class="collection">
<!-- <li class="collection-item">John Smith</li> -->
</ul>
```

In this solution I change your code to put result in get block..so that its will be work ...

Another Solution: 
You can resolve this issue too by using async/await in ES6, promise ...etc check this example: [Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Answer (score 0):

All you're doing is setting a variable. You need to actually `console.log` it:

```
$.each(data.events[id].assistants, function(index, value) {
  if (value == 'undefined' || value == null) {
    html = '<li class="collection-item">No hay asistentes registrados.</li>';
  } else {
    html += '<li class="collection-item">' + value.name + '</li>';
  }
  console.log(html);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you change code like

```
insted of return html; in function --> $("#assistants").append(html);

on function call just call function like : getAssistants(1);
```

check fiddle
       https://jsfiddle.net/jsaf1btz/2/